# Mysql database restore

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql

My mysql backup is running everyday at 4 am & accidently my database got corrupted at 7am. Now how to restore data updated between time period of 4am & 7am

Comment: Do you have a binlog? Or a slave that got all the data? If not: you're lost (unless you can recover the actual corupted db).

Comment: never say never :)

Comment: Are the tables InnoDB or MyISAM

Comment: tables are InnoDB

Answer (score 2):

- Copy your your original datadir (by default /var/lib/mysql on Linux) to safe place.
- Restore database from the last backup
- Download and compile [recovery toolkit](https://twindb.com/undrop-tool-for-innodb/)

If innodb_file_per_table is ON

- Split each ibd file with stream_parser
- Take *.page file with minimal id and fetch records with c_parser. Save output to a file.

  ```
  ./c_parser -f pages-mytable.ibd/FIL_PAGE_INDEX/<minimal id>.page \
    -t path/to/create_statements/mytable.sql \
    > dumps/default/mytable 
    2> dumps/default/mytable.sql
  ```

If innodb_file_per_table is OFF

- Recover [InnoDB Dictionary](https://twindb.com/how-to-recover-innodb-dictionary/)
- Get index_id for mytable from the dictionary and run c_parser as in the example above.

  - Change REPLACE in dumps/default/mytable.sql to IGNORE
  - Load the dump

    mysql db < dumps/default/mytable.sql

Comment: @Kuzminsky, Can u please help me elaborate, what is <minimal id> and /path/to/create_statements/. Should I have to create the file with create_statements for all the table.

Comment: path/to/create_statements/mytable.sql is a file with CREATE TABLE statement.
You need to know index_id of your table. The table name => index_id correspondence is stored in the dictionary. In case of innodb_file_per_table=ON index_id of your table is just the minimal index_id out of all available. Check my posts - there is a comprehensive description how InnoDB stores data on disk